livewire - wire:navigate load from side
I'm using Livewire, Alpine.js, and Tailwind CSS in my project. I'm encountering an issue where, when I load a page with wire:navigate, there is an animation that causes the page to slide in from right to left. I can't figure out where this animation is coming from or how to remove it.
Here are the steps I've taken so far to debug the issue:
Attempted to delete the CSS that might be causing the animation.
Tried changing the layout to see if the problem persists.
None of these steps resolved the issue.
You can see the animation in this GIF:
click to see the image
How can I debug this further or remove the slide-in animation? Any advice on what might be causing this or where to look would be greatly appreciated.
